# Do .min Files Bloat a Git Repository?

Tags: git, repository, minify

I have two files: `A.js` and `A.min.js` (these files are the same, save the minification).

If I add both these files

```
git add -A
```

Which file addition takes up the most space in my repo?

Now if I edit the `A.js` and minify to `A.min.js` and commit again

```
git add -p
```

Which modification takes up the most space in my repo?

My logic is that minified files often have the bulk of their content on a single line, as opposed to their unminified versions which have their content on multiple lines. So when git has to track a change to one (sometimes very) long line, does it take up more space than if the 'line' has less content?

Answer (score 3):

My logic is that if you have a set of files A that you edit, and a set of files B that are always generated from A and never edited, then you should *not* add B to your repo, but instead let whoever clones your repo generate them by themselves to save space. This is why coding projects usually git-ignore binaries, generated documentation and such.

So even though I don't know if minified files will actually be more efficient for Git to process or not, my answer is always push the `.js` files, and always git-ignore the `.min.js` files. The efficiency trade-off, if any, can't be that high.

Comment: Great point, and not one I've not considered. The problem is that the .gitignore file would get quite difficult to manage, especially when new standalone .min files (like jquery-ui) are constantly added to a multi-site project with multiple developers.

Comment: Not really. `*.min.js` ignores _all_ minified JS files in your project. Just put the ones you don't want to ignore in a specific directory and make an exception for that directory e.g `!vendor/*.min.js`

Comment: Yes but that's not what I'm after, there are a lot of `.min.js` files that need to be included and cannot be generated from non-existent unminified versions without some effort.

Comment: Also a good idea, although moving what could be hundreds of files to the `/vendor` dir and updating each call to match the new path sounds unnecessarily tedious

Comment: I would accept your answer but it doesn't explicitly answer the question